# MYSQL query : query displays the second to last line of data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask how to display data from second to last line?

```
+----+------------------+-------+
| id |   nama_makanan   | harga |
+----+------------------+-------+
|  1 | Ayam Katsu       | 18000 |
|  2 | Udon Daging Sapi | 26000 |
|  3 | Mie Ramen Gila   | 24000 |
|  4 | Cah Kangkung     | 16000 |
|  5 | Sayur Nangka     | 10000 |
+----+------------------+-------+
```

for example, if use the limit so like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_makanan ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1,4
```

results:

```
+----+------------------+-------+
| id |   nama_makanan   | harga |
+----+------------------+-------+
|  2 | Udon Daging Sapi | 26000 |
|  3 | Mie Ramen Gila   | 24000 |
|  4 | Cah Kangkung     | 16000 |
|  5 | Sayur Nangka     | 10000 |
+----+------------------+-------+
```

but that's static, what if the data is very much in the table? how to take second data until last data?

Comment: You can just use a very big number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to your desired results using left join

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tbl_makanan a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tbl_makanan
    ORDER BY id ASC 
    LIMIT 1
) b USING (id)
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/DBK42914)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a very large value of "4".  This will work on most tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_makanan
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1, 999999999;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (here is a working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/749c67/1)):

```
SELECT id, nama_makanan, harga FROM tbl_makanan WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM tbl_makanan) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you.. :)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_makanan
ORDER BY id ASC 
OFFSET 1 ROWS
```